# Hello i have problem to send email for reset password from frontend to user email in postman everything is good but in console i got error

Tags: reactjs, vite

`i got problem for my ForgotPssword.jsx how to send token for reset password from frontend to user email for reset password file here is the code of redux js files and frontend jsx file so i cannot find problem i try solutions all over the net but i cannot fix it so can u tell me where is error and how to fix it`

`this is userApiSlice.js`

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
    userInfo: localStorage.getItem('userInfo')
        ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'))
        : null,
};

export const validEmail = (val) => /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(val);

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'auth',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setCredentials: (state, action) => {
            state.userInfo = action.payload;
            localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(action.payload));
        },
        logout: (state, action) => {
            state.userInfo = null;
            localStorage.removeItem('userInfo');
        },

        resetnewPassword: (state, action) => {
            state.resetnewPassword = action.payload;
            localStorage.setItem('userInfo', 'email', JSON.stringify(action.payload));
        }
    },
});
```

`this is my authSlice.js file`

```
export const { setCredentials, logout, resetnewPassword } = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;

import { apiSlice } from "./apiSlice";
const USERS_URL = '/api/users';

export const usersApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        login: builder.mutation({
            query: (data) => ({
                url: `${USERS_URL}/login`,
                method: 'POST',
                body: data,
            }), 
        }),

        logout: builder.mutation({
            query: () => ({
                url: `${USERS_URL}/logout`,
                method: 'POST',
            }),
        }),

        register: builder.mutation({
            query: (data) => ({
                url: `${USERS_URL}`,
                method: 'POST',
                body: data,
            }),
        }),

        resetPassword: builder.mutation({
            query: (data) => ({
                url: `${USERS_URL}/reset-password`,
                method: 'POST',
                body: data,
            }),
        }),

        newPassword: builder.mutation({
            query: (data) => ({
                url: `${USERS_URL}/new-password`,
                method: 'POST',
                body: data,
            }),
        }),



    }),
});

export const {
    useLoginMutation,
    useLogoutMutation,
    useRegisterMutation,
    useResetPasswordMutation,
    useNewPasswordMutation,
} = usersApiSlice;
```

`here is frontend jsx file`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { FaAt } from 'react-icons/fa'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { toast } from 'react-toastify'
import { setCredentials } from '../Redux/Api/authSlice'
import { useResetPasswordMutation } from '../Redux/Api/userApiSlice'

import '../styles/Login.css'
import { validEmail } from '../Redux/Api/authSlice'


`here is frontend jsx file `
export default function ForgotPassword() {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const [resetPassword] = useResetPasswordMutation()

    const { resetnewPassword } = useState((state) => state.auth);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (resetnewPassword)
            navigate('/')

    }, [navigate, userInfo])

    const passwordHandler = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (validEmail(email)) {
            try {
                const res = await resetPassword({ email }).unwrap()
                dispatch(setCredentials({ ...res }))
                dispatch(newPassword({ ...res }))
                navigate('/reset-password')
            } catch (err) {
                toast.error(err?.data?.message || err.error)
            }

        }


        return (

            <div className="container">
                <div className="row w-500">
                    <div className="col-sm-12 d-flex">
                        <div className="login-card card-block auth-body">
                            <div className="authbox">
                                <div className="brand-logo text-center">Bubllee</div>
                                <h5 className='text-secondary text-center' style={{ fontFamily: 'Indie Flower' }} >Please enter your email to reset password</h5>
                                <br />
                                <div className="col-12">
                                    <form action="" className='w-100' onSubmit={passwordHandler}>
                                        <div className="input-group">
                                            <span className='input-group-addon'>
                                                <FaAt className='icon iconfont' />
                                            </span>
                                            <input type="email" placeholder='Enter Email' className='form-control' required autoComplete='off'
                                                value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} style={{ borderRadius: '20px' }} />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="links text-right ">
                                            <div className="registration-link">
                                                <p>Go back to</p>
                                                <Link to='/login' className='text-left f-w-600'>
                                                    <p className='iconfont iconfont-lock'>Sign In</p>
                                                </Link>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <div className="m-t-20">
                                            <button type='submit' className="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block m-b-10 signupbtn">Reset Password</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }

}
```